# Page Numbering from this script

Tags: php

This script takes every image in a folder and shows it on a webpage. Is there a way to show like an simple page number like 1,2,3,4,5 every 10 images or so? I try to google some things but all I can find is with a database. Is it even possible with an array?

```
<?php

    # To prevent browser error output
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');
    # Path to image folder
    $imagefolder = 'img/';
    # Show only these file types in the image folder
    $imagetypes = '{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.JPEG,*.png,*.PNG,*.gif,*.GIF}';
    # Add images to array
    $images = glob($imagefolder.$imagetypes, GLOB_BRACE);
    # Sort the images based on its 'last modified' time stamp
    $sortedImages = array();
    $count = count($images);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $sortedImages[date ('YmdHis', filemtime($images[$i])).$i] = $images[$i];
    }

    # Set to 'false' if you want the oldest images to appear first
    $newest_images_first = true;
    # Sort images in array
    if($newest_images_first) {
        krsort($sortedImages);
    } else {
        ksort($sortedImages);
    }

    # Generate the HTML output
    writeHtml('<ul class="ins-imgs">');
    foreach ($sortedImages as $image) {
        # Get the name of the image, stripped from image folder path and file type extension
        $name = 'Image name: '.substr($image,strlen($imagefolder),strpos($image, '.')-strlen($imagefolder));
        # Get the 'last modified' time stamp, make it human readable
        $last_modified = '(last modified: '.date('F d Y H:i:s', filemtime($image)).')';
        # Begin adding
        writeHtml('<li class="ins-imgs-li">');
        writeHtml('<div class="ins-imgs-label">'.$name.' '.$last_modified.'</div>');
        writeHtml('<div class="ins-imgs-img"><a name="'.$image.'" href="#'.$image.'">');
        writeHtml('<img src="'.$image.'" alt="'. $name.'" title="'. $name.'">');
        writeHtml('</a></div>');
        writeHtml('</li>');
    }
    writeHtml('</ul>');
    writeHtml('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ins-imgs.css">');
    # Convert HTML to JS
    function writeHtml($html) {
        echo "document.write('".$html."');\n";



    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Use a GET variable to move pages:

```
$perPage = 5;
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $perPage;
$end = ($page * $perPage) - 1;

for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
  $image = $sortedImages[$i];
  // rest of your code
}
```

Or

```
 $perPage = 5;
 $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
 $start = ($page - 1) * $perPage;
 $images = array_slice($sortedImages, $start, $perPage);

 foreach ($images as $image) {
   // rest of your code
 }
```

For next page links, just do `<a href="?page=<?php echo $page + 1; ?>">Next</a>`. Should be able to work the rest out.